# monitoring static variable inside a function in eclipse CDT

Tags: c, debugging, eclipse-cdt

In c, when a variable is defined static within a function, the value of the variable is retained all the time. So probably, it's stored in the bss or data section.

However, in Eclipse CDT debugging, when trying to inspect this variable, typing the variable name in the expression pane only display the variable when the stack frame is in the function, like local variable.

Is it a bug in eclipse ?

Edit:
In IAR Embedded workbench, static variables in functions can be watched outside the function in debugging, so it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

While the variable is, in fact, stored in the heap... it remains that the **scope** of the variable is local to the function. It's value has no meaning outside of that function and it should never change when outside of the function... unless you're passing pointers to it around, in which case you can view it in any function that has access to that pointer.

So... no... it's not a bug.

Comment: In IAR Embedded workbench, static variables in functions can be watched outside the function, so it's possible.

Comment: Perhaps... but they are out of scope nonetheless. I would argue that IAR is breaking the encapsulation of the variable's declared scope in doing so.

Comment: Why do we care about encapsulation, we're not doing "object oriented" debugging. Let's say for instance I a have a function with a static variable that holds the number of times the function was called. this is valuable information for debugging even outside the function's scope

Comment: We're not doing object oriented debugging... the variable is undefined out of scope. If you want to inspect memory, then you watch a memory address... or qualify the scope in the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify the static variable with the function in order to determine the scope, e.g. `foo::myvar` if `myvar` is defined in function `foo`.